# Customer Login not working into iframe for magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, csp

I am working on magento website http://20.204.34.13/  i want to load this site into iframe. Site is loading but customer login is not working. Does anyone can suggest solution for this.
Below is iframe html.

If iframe is on same domain then it works fine see example http://20.204.34.13/pub/demoscript/iframe_check.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can also use the CSS height and width properties to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="http://20.204.34.13/" style="height:600px;width:300px" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```